# C++ Pushback vector<struct>MyVector And Error C2664

Tags: c++, vector, struct, push-back

First of all I'm pretty new to vectors themself, so bear with me please.

I'm trying to make a vector that contains 2strings, int and a float.

This is my struct:

```
struct OpiskelijanTiedot {

   string etunimi;
   string sukunimi;
   int HarjMaara;
   float Arvosana;

   OpiskelijanTiedot() : etunimi(), sukunimi(), HarjMaara(), Arvosana() {}
   OpiskelijanTiedot(string const& e, string const& s, int const& h, float const& a) :
         etunimi(e), sukunimi(s), HarjMaara(h), Arvosana(a) {}
   bool operator<(OpiskelijanTiedot const& rhs) const
   {
      return sukunimi < rhs.sukunimi;
   }
};
```

Then in Main.cpp I made a vector like this: `vector<OpiskelijanTiedot> Tiedot;`

And in my functions.cpp I have this:

```
void oppilas(vector<OpiskelijanTiedot>Tiedot, int laskuri) {
   OpiskelijanTiedot temp;
   cout << "Etunimi: ";
   cin.ignore();
   cin >> temp.etunimi;
   Tiedot.push_back(temp.etunimi);
   cout << "Sukunimi: ";
   cin >> temp.sukunimi;
   Tiedot.push_back(temp.sukunimi);
   cout << "Tehtyjen harjoitustehtavien maara: ";
   cin >> temp.HarjMaara;
   Tiedot.push_back(temp.HarjMaara);
   cout << "Harjoitustyon arvosana: ";
   cin >> temp.Arvosana;
   Tiedot.push_back(temp.Arvosana);
}
```

So I'm getting this error:

> Description    Project File    Line
>   Error   C2664
>   'void
>   std::vector>::push_back(const
>   OpiskelijanTiedot &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'float' to
>   'OpiskelijanTiedot &&'

I've been searching about this problem for a long time now and can't get rid of this, so any help or pointing me to right direction is greatly appreciated. I'm guessing it somehow has a problem with me not telling what's string int etc, but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tiedot is a vector of OpiskelijanTiedot, while temp.Arvosana is a float.

you should do

```
Tiedot.push_back(temp)
```

Comment: Oh god, that was easier than I thought, I tried literally everything else. Thank you, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your function has syntax errors, which were pointed out by the compiler. You cannot push objects of type `string`, `int`, and `float` to a `vector` of `OpiskelijanTiedot`s.

The other error is that your function is adding an item to the input `vector` but the change only affects the copy of the `vector` since the argument is object, not a reference. If you want the change of adding an item to the vector to be reflected in the calling function, you'll have to change the argument type to be a reference.

```
void oppilas(vector<OpiskelijanTiedot>& Tiedot, int laskuri) {
                                 //  ^^^ Change the argument type to a reference
   OpiskelijanTiedot temp;
   cout << "Etunimi: ";
   cin.ignore();
   cin >> temp.etunimi;
   cout << "Sukunimi: ";
   cin >> temp.sukunimi;
   cout << "Tehtyjen harjoitustehtavien maara: ";
   Tiedot.push_back(temp.HarjMaara);
   cout << "Harjoitustyon arvosana: ";
   cin >> temp.Arvosana;

   // Add the object to the vector.
   Tiedot.push_back(temp);
}
```